# List item count ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

How can I get the number of items
Can i do this.item.count ?

```
this.todoService.getItems().then((data) => {
          this.items = data;


    }, (err) => {
        console.log("not allowed");
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array in javascript has a .length property.

More info at [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)